# Rod broke piston's stock

Tags: chevrolet, connecting-rod

I have a 2006 Chevy with a 6.0 and it broke a rod so I took a saw and cut the rod off the piston  With the stuck piston is it OK to drive it still starts.

Comment: Do you mean limp it to a garage where you can get the engine replaced or drive as though nothing had happened?

Answer (score 1):

At this point the damage has been done. So while it may start in this condition it's going to be only a short time before you have additional failures.

Two main reasons:

1. Whatever caused the first rod to break, likely an oiling problem, is still an issue and other rods and the mains are likely damaged and may fail at any time.
2. You have caused an unbalanced condition by cutting the rod and that will also accelerate wear.

I'd plan on pulling the engine and doing a total rebuild provided the engine block is undamaged, which is unlikely.  A reman or used engine is probably your best bet.